# No Suitable Constructor, and an incompatible declaration error

Tags: c++, constructor, switch-statement, declaration, header-files

My header file:

```
// Definition of class SunshineWeb that counts Product 1, Product 2
// and Product 3 retail prices. Refer to Project 2.cpp for member
// functions.
using namespace std;
#include <string> // program uses C++ standard string class
// SunshineWeb class definition
class SunshineWeb
{
public:
    SunshineWeb( string ); // constructor initialises customer name
    void setCustomerName( string ); // function to get customer name
    string getCustomerName; // function to retrieve customer name
    void displayMessage(); // displays a welcome message
    void inputProducts(); // inputs a number of products
    void displayProductTotal(); // total number of what products
private:
    string CustomerName; // customer's name
    int Product1Count;
    int Product2Count;
    int Product3Count;
}; // end of class SunshineWeb
```

Member-function definitions, switch counter and all that:

```
// Project 2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// Member-function definitions for class SunshineWeb that uses a switch
// statement to count Products, then calculate and display Product total.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SunshineWeb.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//constructor initialises CustomerName with string supplied as arguement;
//initialises counter data member to 0
SunshineWeb::SunshineWeb( string name )
{
    setCustomerName( name ); // validates and store CustomerName
    Product1Count = 0; // initialises count of Product 1 to 0
    Product2Count = 0; // initialises count of Product 2 to 0
    Product3Count = 0; // initialises count of Product 3 to 0
} // end SunshineWeb constructor

// function to set the customer's name; limits to 25 or fewer characters
void SunshineWeb::setCustomerName( string name )
{
    if ( name.length() <= 25 ) // if the name has 25 or fewer characters
        CustomerName = name;
    else // if name is longer than 25 characters
    { // sets CustomerName to the first 25 characters of parameter name
        CustomerName = name.substr( 0, 25 ); // selects first 25 characters
        cout << "Name \"" << name << "\" exceeds maximum length (25). \n"
            << "Limiting CustomerName to first 25 characters.\n" << endl;
    } // end if... else statement
} // end function setCustomerName

// function to retrieve customer's name
string SunshineWeb::getCustomerName()
{
    return CustomerName;
}

// displays a welcome message to the user
void SunshineWeb::displayMessage()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Sunshine Web's store application!" << endl;
} // end function displayMessage

void SunshineWeb::inputProducts()
{
    int products; // products entered by user
    cout << "Enter 1 for Product 1, 2 for Product 2, " << endl
        << "3 for Product 3, and EOF character to end input." << endl;

    // loops until user inputs end-of-file key sequence
    while( ( products = cin.get() ) != EOF )
    {
        // determine which product was entered
        switch (products) // switch statement nested in while
        {
        case '1': // The character 1 was inputted
            ++Product1Count; // increment Product1Count
            break; // necessary to exit the switch

        case '2': // The character 2 was inputted
            ++Product2Count; // increment Product2Count
            break; // necessary to exit the switch

        case '3': // The character 3 was inputted
            ++Product3Count; // increment Product3Count
            break; // necessary to exit the switch

        case '\n': // ignores new lines,
        case '\t': // tabs,
        case ' ' : // and spaces inbetween input
            break; // exit switch

        default: // catch all other characters
            cout << "Incorrect character entered."
                << "Please enter 1, 2, 3 or EOF key." << endl;
            break; // exit switch
        } // end switch
    } // end while
} // end function inputProducts

// displays the quantity of the product and retail total
void SunshineWeb::displayProductTotal()
{
    // output summary of user orders
    cout << "Quantity of each Product ordererd by the user:"
        << "\nProduct 1, at $22.98 per unit: " << Product1Count // displays number of Product 1
        << "\nProduct 2, at $34.50 per unit: " << Product2Count // displays number of Product 2
        << "\nProduct 3, at $99.98 per unit: " << Product3Count // displays number of Product 3
        << endl;
    // algorithim used to calculate total price
        int total = static_cast <double> (Product1Count*22.98) + static_cast <double>(Product2Count*34.50) + static_cast<double>(Product3Count*99.98);
    cout << "The total price of your order is: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << total << endl;
} // end function displayProductTotal
```

Problem begins at `string SunshineWeb::getCustomerName()`, where it underlines `getCustomerName()` and states the following:

```
Error:declaration is incompatible with "std::string SunshineWeb::getCustomerName"
(declared at line 12 of "c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\SunshineWeb.h")
```

And this is the main file / executor thingy:

```
// creates SunshineWeb object, inputs products and displays
// total quantity and retail price of products inputted.
#include "SunshineWeb.h" // includes definition of class SunshineWeb

int main()
{
    // creates SunshineWeb object
    SunshineWeb mySunshineWeb("Sunshine Web Store");
    mySunshineWeb.displayMessage();
    mySunshineWeb.inputProducts();
    mySunshineWeb.displayProductTotal();
} // end main
```

My second problem is with `SunshineWeb mySunshineWeb("Sunshine Web Store");`, where it underlines `Sunshine Web Store` and states:

```
 Error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char[19]" to "SunshineWeb"
```

Just beginning to learn C++ object orientation programming, and this is a program I wrote for class - what gives? I googled and went through my notes, but it doesn't help / solve this problem at all. What really bugs me most is the no suitable constructor part, as I can simply throw all Customer Name related functions out of the window, as I haven't even implemented it yet, seeing as I can't get it working ; but maybe there's something I'm missing. Either way... I need help! Please save my baby!

**Edit** : Thanks for the help, I've noticed my error and tried tweaking it like suggested, so my header file now looks like :

```
// Definition of class SunshineWeb that counts Product 1, Product 2
// and Product 3 retail prices. Refer to Project 2.cpp for member
// functions.
#include <string> // program uses C++ standard string class
// SunshineWeb class definition
class SunshineWeb
{
public:
    SunshineWeb( std::string ); // constructor initialises customer name
    void setCustomerName( std::string ); // function to get customer name
    std::string getCustomerName(); // function to retrieve customer name
    void displayMessage(); // displays a welcome message
    void inputProducts(); // inputs a number of products
    void displayProductTotal(); // total number of what products
private:
    std::string CustomerName; // customer's name
    int Product1Count;
    int Product2Count;
    int Product3Count;
}; // end of class SunshineWeb
```

This fixed the incompatible declaration error (a simple typo mistake) from earlier, and I'm not sure if it fixed the error with no suitable constructor, because while the nasty red underline is gone, I still can't run the program : I opened up the error list from Visual Studio 2010, I see a couple of errors:

```
Error   5   error C2065: 'mySunshineWeb' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 9
Error   7   error C2065: 'mySunshineWeb' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 10
Error   9   error C2065: 'mySunshineWeb' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 11
Error   2   error C2065: 'SunshineWeb' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 8
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mySunshineWeb'   c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 8
Error   6   error C2228: left of '.displayMessage' must have class/struct/union c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 9
Error   10  error C2228: left of '.displayProductTotal' must have class/struct/union    c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 11
Error   8   error C2228: left of '.inputProducts' must have class/struct/union  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 10
Error   4   error C3861: 'mySunshineWeb': identifier not found  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 8
Warning 1   warning C4627: '#include "SunshineWeb.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project 2\project 2\sunshineweb.cpp 3
```

Yes, I am a complete amateur making (mostly) silly mistakes, but for the love of my life I can't seem to find a solution to my seemingly-simple problems. These problems makes no sense whatsoever, and I'm quadruple checking everything. Thanks for the help (and patience displayed), I really appreciate it.

Comment: there is typo in your function declaration `string getCustomerName` should be `string getCustomerName()` in header file

Comment: try to include these #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SunshineWeb.h"
#include <iomanip>
 in your H file instead of cpp file.

Comment: Yeah, stupid typo on my part, thanks keety

@bluebrain
And how would that solve anything - wouldn't that make a ton more problems?

Comment: @bluebrain No, those header files should be in the source file like it is. The problem it seems, is that `"stdafx.h"` must be included in the main source file as well. For MSVC projects using pre-compiled headers it should _always_ be the first header file in all source files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That did it, thanks! I'm amazed at some of the things I get stumped at!

Answer (score 0):

```
string getCustomerName; // member function missing () in class SunshineWeb definition.
```

to

```
string getCustomerName(); // function to retrieve customer name
```

- Use C++ initializer lists.
- [Why is including "using namespace std;" in to a header is a bad idea ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: Wow, that was a really dumb error on my part, thanks for the heads up. Something's freakier happened though, and that's there's no error at all, and it won't run! Updated original post.